# how can i receive call when my application was killed and how to know person was busy on another call?

Tags: flutter, dart, callkit

I am doing call functionality using [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming). My question is how can i receive call when my application was killed and how to know person was busy on another call

I tried using getActiveCalls method of flutter_callkit_incoming package but i did not getting active call in android. it was give only last calls